# DES encryption using native java classes

Tags: java, algorithm, encryption, cryptography, encryption-symmetric

Trying to create java class which will encrypt and decrypt as like C# code in below.

Below is the code for C#, I need to convert it to Java. Can someone help me how to do it?

I've been doing this for almost 3 days yet can't find any solutions on how to convert it. I am new to crypto.

Note - It seems C# code used ACME libraries. But in my java, i should not use ACME jar files.

My question is the string encrypted in native java classes should be length multiple of 8 bytes as per the acme. In java how can we achieve the same. Due to this i am getting error as `Input length not multiple of 8 bytes`

**C# Code**

```
 public static string EncryptBase64(string key, string clearText)
        {
            if (key.Length > 8)
                key = key.Substring(0, 8);

            byte[] keyBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
            byte[] clearBytes = GetClearTextBytes(clearText);

            // calculate the number of legitimate bytes in the last block
            byte lastByte = (byte)(8 - (clearBytes.Length - textEncoding.GetByteCount(clearText)));

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

            DES des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
            des.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
            des.GenerateIV();

            System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform ict = des.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, des.IV);
            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, ict, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
            cs.FlushFinalBlock();
            ms.Close();

            byte[] cipherBytes = ms.ToArray();

            // create a byte output stream for Acme compatibality
            MemoryStream acmeCompatStream = new MemoryStream();

            // Acme writes the IV to the frist block
            acmeCompatStream.Write(des.IV, 0, 8);

            for (int i = 0; i < cipherBytes.Length; i = i + 8)
            {
                // write the next block
                acmeCompatStream.Write(cipherBytes, i, 8);

                // write the number of valid bytes in the block
                if (i == cipherBytes.Length - 8)
                    acmeCompatStream.WriteByte(lastByte);
                else
                    acmeCompatStream.WriteByte(8);
            }

            acmeCompatStream.Close();

            cipherBytes = acmeCompatStream.ToArray();

            return (System.Convert.ToBase64String(cipherBytes));
        }
```

Below is the code which i have tried in java. I have two different encryption function. I have tried both of the encryption method. But both are not giving expected encrypted string to decrypt in acme.

**Java code with native java libries -**

```
    package com.abc.some.common.nativeDES;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class DESEncrypt {
    public String keyValue = "123456789";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?><SomeRequest><OrderNumber>1564578</OrderNumber></SomeRequest>";
        String codedtext ="not encrypted";
        try{
            codedtext = new DESEncrypt().Encrypt1(text);
            //codedtext = new DESEncrypt().encrypt(text);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in Encryption.. " + e.getMessage());
        }

        System.out.println(codedtext);

    }
    public String Encrypt1(String CXML) {
        try {
            KeySpec myKey = new DESKeySpec(keyValue.getBytes("UTF8"));
        SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES").generateSecret(myKey);
        Cipher ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
        ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] data = CXML.getBytes("ASCII");

        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/NoPadding");
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

        byte[] crypt = ecipher.doFinal(data);
        //String encoded = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(crypt.toString().getBytes("ASCII"));
        //String encoded = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(crypt.getBytes("ASCII"));

        String encoded = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(crypt).toString();

        System.out.println(encoded);

        return encoded;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        return null;
    }    
}
```

But I have used below java file to encrypt the string which is using acme jar files. This was working as expected. But as per my project requirement i should not use the external(ACME) jar files.

**Java code with ACME Jar files -**

```
package com.abc.common.encryption;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import Acme.Crypto.SecurityDES;

public class ESBCryptoDES {

    public static void main(String args[]){
//      DESEncrypt("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?><SomeRequest><OrderNumber>1564578</OrderNumber></SomeRequest>"
//              ,"D:\\name\\proj\\order\\Encryption\\st.properties");
        DESDecrypt("vQ9C7ZrLzjQpHvZjtHvUb0mFCr824/aClY2jKbeciczsRVr+kEETFvDuHgdBS/aLskYV3WX3U5TANSlK3pH80r3xOyn9Q8rTjlB/yXyU7J9MgibJ66jJx0wrqeloAkmQzqj+b5+I/lXANSlK3pH80kT1D+jqWAeV"
                ,"D:\\name\\proj\\order\\Encryption\\stDecrypt.properties");
    }
    public static String DESEncrypt(String SourceStrForCrypt,String PropPath) {
        String encrypt = "";
        String decrypt = "";
        // Load the property file.
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        try {
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(PropPath);
            prop.load(in);
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in loading property file.. "
                    + e.getMessage());
        }

        // Encrypt the given content.
        try {
            String keypath = prop.getProperty("proj.sample.DEV");
            System.out.println("sample" + keypath);

            String SourceToEncrypt = SourceStrForCrypt; //This will provide the xml string to encrypt
            // Encryption
            encrypt = SecurityDES.DesEncryptBase64(keypath,SourceToEncrypt);
            System.out.println(encrypt);
            // Decryption
            decrypt = SecurityDES.DesDecryptBase64(keypath, encrypt);
            System.out.println(decrypt);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in Encryption.. " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return encrypt;
    }

    public static String DESDecrypt(String SourceStrForCrypt,String PropPath) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String decrypt = "";

        Properties prop = new Properties();

        try {
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(PropPath);
            prop.load(in);
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in loading property file.. "+ e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            String abc_keyPath = prop
                    .getProperty("proj.abc.DEV");
            System.out.println("keypath" + abc_keyPath);
            // Decryption
            decrypt = SecurityDES.DesDecryptBase64(abc_keyPath, SourceStrForCrypt);
            System.out.println("decrypted..."+decrypt);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in Encryption.. " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return decrypt;

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, the Java code seems working to me. I tried and it is actually encoding the string. What is the problem?

Comment: My question is the string encrypted in native java classes should be decrypted in the acme java class files. Basically i need to write some java class without ACMe jars to encrypt the data. and in other end they will use ACME to decrypt it.